# Screen readers on Raspberry Pi 3 [and Orca on Rpi4B buster release 2020feb05]

Tags: pi-3, pi-4, accessibility

Do you know what Screen readers work on the Pi 3?
(A screen reader reads out text on the screen and is what I need to enable to be able to use devices because I am blind)

Comment: Did you read the article on raspberrypi.org here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-vi-accessibility-for-visually-impaired-pi-users/ ?  There are some links to a discussion group etc where you might find the info you need.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101791/discussion-on-question-by-legendusmaximus-screen-readers-on-the-raspberry-pi-3).

Comment: Hi @LegendusMaximus, Long time no see. In case you have not heard about it already, Raspbian now supports Orca screen reader! : (1) 
"Raspbian Buster Gets New Features in Big Update By Ash Puckett 7 hours ago New changes and lots of features!"
https://www.tomshardware.com/news/raspbian-buster-gets-new-features-in-big-update. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple.

**Orca** is a popular screen reader that works on the Raspberry Pi, and you can install it by typing from the terminal "sudo apt-get install gnome-orca". Here's that command pronunciated: "s u d o  space  a p t  dash  g e t  space  i n s t a l l  space  g n o m e  dash  o r c a"

**yasr** is another screen reader that works on the Raspberry Pi. It reads the terminal, so you would be able to do alot with it as the terminal is very powerful. You can install it by typing from the terminal "sudo apt-get install yasmr". Here's that command pronunciated: "s u d o  space  a p t  dash  g e t  space  i n s t a l l  space  y a s m r"

If you have any further questions, please let us know.

Comment: While this answer is a good summary, it does not explain how to use these screen readers once installed.

Comment: I apogize. So to run orca, type from the terminal "orca". That should start it up.

Answer (score 1):

***Answer***

Yes, I would recommend Orca which is now supported on Rpi3/4 buster release 2020feb05.  JAWS and NVDA are also good, but they are not free.

---

*Update 2020feb12*

[Raspberry Pi's Raspbian gets new features: File manager, Thonny updates, Support for Orca - Liam Tung 2020feb11](https://www.zdnet.com/article/raspberry-pis-raspbian-gets-new-features-file-manager-thonny-python-ide-updates/)

...

This Raspbian release brings accessibility improvements to the desktop in the form of support for the Orca screen reader. The tool uses speech, reads menus, windows titles, and button labels. Even though it is a Linux application, visually impaired people have found it didn't work with Raspbian.

"After quite a bit of fiddling and head-scratching, Orca now works as intended. It will read out many of the pre-installed applications, and should work with a lot of other Linux software packages as well," said Long.

---

You might like to read the chat record (Ref 2) and my experience on installing Orca on Rpi4B buster (Ref 11)

---

***References***

(1) [Raspbian Buster Gets New Features {inclduing Orca] in Big Update - Ash Puckett 2020feb10][2](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/raspbian-buster-gets-new-features-in-big-update)

(2) [Chat record/Discussion on question by LegendusMaximus: Screen readers on the Raspberry Pi 3](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101791/discussion-on-question-by-legendusmaximus-screen-readers-on-the-raspberry-pi-3)

(3) [Orca, An Introduction](https://help.gnome.org/users/orca/stable/introduction.html.en)

(4) [Orca User Guide](https://help.gnome.org/users/orca/stable/)

(5) [Screen Reders - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader)

(6) [List of screen readers - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screen_readers)

(7) [Linux SpeakUp Screen Reader User Guide (Last modified 2010)](http://www.linux-speakup.org/spkguide.txt)

(8) [NVDS and JAWS: NVDA (NonVisual Desktop Access) Screen Reader – CNIB 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ryeDJdDIVA)

(9) [JAWS (Job Access with Speech): Introduction - West Virginia University 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1gHxM1nP00)

(10) [JAWS (Job Access with Speech) Screen Reader Demo - Cheese Cake Factory 2017](http://youtube.com/watch?v=Q1gHxM1nP00) 
(11) [Orca Installation Record - tlfong01 2019dec04](https://penzu.com/public/16bf07c0)

---

***Appendices***

(a) [Orca Installation Record - tlfong01 2019apr12](https://penzu.com/public/16bf07c0)

---

*End of answer*